# Hotkey to change Brush Hardness in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, creative-cloud, hotkeys

Is there a keyboard shortcut to switch between soft and hard brushes in Photoshop CC?

Comment: Brian, we tend here at **GDSE** to *avoid* questions which are both *easily googleable* and also available instantly within given software's online help (I found an answer for this in *less than ten seconds*) and it doesn't, based on your question as posted, look like ***any*** effort went into this query. I think it really would be worth your looking at [ask] to get a sense of how we prefer questions here - the goal is to further your and everyone's knowledge and skill *beyond* easy tech support Q/A level issues. [https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/default-keyboard-shortcuts.html]

Answer (score 2):

There are keyboard shortcuts for adjusting the brush hardness up or down.

Use <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>{</kbd>/<kbd>}</kbd> for harder and softer

It adjusts it in 25% increments, pressing it four times will bring you to 0% or 100%.

---

You can also delete all the other brushes from **Brush Presets** besides for the 2 that you want to be able to toggle.

Then use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd><</kbd>/<kbd>></kbd> to select the first/last brush.

---

There is also a keyboard and mouse combination for changing brush size and hardness.

Hold down <kbd>Alt</kbd> and *Right Click + Drag*;

- Up/Down for brush hardness
- Right/Left for brush size

[image: GIF Showing above process]
<sub>▲ Holding down <kbd>Alt</kbd></sub>

(On macOS it's <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd>+drag)

Comment: Is that alt/drag Windows only, or does it need setting up in prefs? I can't get Mac to do it with any key/drag combo.

Comment: @Tetsujin I updated the answer, it's `Ctrl`+`Option`+`Drag` (not sure about left/right click though - you can let me know)

Comment: \o/ ctrl/alt [opt] drag works. Only been using Photoshop 25 years & never knew that one, thank you ;-))  [it's left-click, btw]