# how to set shortcut for brush size in photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, brush, shortcuts

in photoshop, <kbd>[</kbd><kbd>]</kbd> is too far from main shortcut and <kbd>c</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> is also has to be hit multiple times until I get the size I want.

I really like kritas brush size shortcut. <kbd>shift</kbd> + pen drag.

Is there anyway that you can change it in photoshop?

thank you!

[image]

I added an image. that setting is almost what I was looking for. you hit alt and drag your pen on tablet, it easily changes brush size but the problem is that you can't draw since the tip is set to right click. krita automatically holds it as click until I hit shift button with default set up.
[image]

Comment: This might be useful to you http://blogs.adobe.com/jkost/2017/05/brushes-and-painting-tool-shortcuts-in-photoshop-cc.html and this as well http://blogs.adobe.com/jkost/2017/05/tips-for-working-with-color-in-photoshop-cc.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hotkey to change Brush Hardness in Photoshop](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/118005/63979)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Photoshop has a nifty dynamic brush size controller built in.

**MacOS**: <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd> and then click-drag.

You'll see a red circle, that's the brush.

- Drag left/right for size
- Drag up/down for hardness.

This *must* also work on Windows
 
I'm uncertain what the equivalent key for `Control` would be... 
maybe <kbd>Alt</kbd> + `Right-click` + `Left-click` + drag all at once.

Comment: I can confirm that Alt+Right-click and drag works on Windows.  Nice tip!

Comment: @Scott Thank you but whenever I push alt it just switches to color picker even if I hit the pen mouse right button first. I am aware of alt + 'mouse' click + drag does that job. my problem is the pen. alt + pen right button + drag doesn't work.

Comment: @Billy Kerr thank you. but I was talking about the pen. sorry I shouldve clarified that

Comment: @Scott I added an image. I guess its just impossible in photoshop...?

Comment: With a tablet the right-click assigned to the stylus might not work (I'm a Mac user). You *really* should mention you are using a tablet and *what brand* of tablet in the question.

Comment: Also, if the **tip** of the stylus is set to right click, you can't then very well left click and drag. The tip can't be both right AND left click. I'd **guess** for a tablet you need Alt+RightClick+LeftClick+drag... @BillyKerr may be able to confirm that... or not `:)` On My Mac it's Control+Option, then tap-drag with the stylus... so theoretically that is RightClick+Alt+LeftClick+Drag -- all at the same time.

Comment: @blenderbaby - that's odd because your question is titled "how to set shortcut for brush size in Photoshop". To be honest with you, you probably need to refer to you graphics tablet user manual.  BTW ~ hardware questions are generally off-topic here.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows you can set `Modifier...` for <kbd>Alt</kbd>+RightClick, holding the set button will increase/decrease brush size when moving pen horizontally and hardness or opacity (set in Tools Preferences) when moving vertically.

[image]

As a bonus, if you hold <kbd>Shift</kbd>, you'll call a HUD color picker

[image]

On a Mac it worked the same until one of the drivers update about a year ago. Now you have to click while holding the modifier button :( Wrote to Wacom support about this several times, no reaction as always.

Comment: I freakin' hate Wacom driver updates `:)` I have yet to see one in the last 10 years that fails to introduce some sort of huge bug. they used to *always* be solid updates... but since roughly 2002.. they *never* are. I always keep the old driver .dmg around to revert because inevitably I will have to 2 or 3 times before they releases a solid driver update.... In other words.... I feel your pain! `:)`

Comment: Oh yes, I tried to stay at those drivers as long as I could but they didn't support my newer tablet :( It's so weird that Windows driver works better now than Mac one, it was the opposite hehe

Answer (score 1):

With Left <kbd>Alt</kbd> + Middle Click + Right Click, I can manage the brush size only with bottom button. With pressing the button, move left/right for diameter size, up/down for hardness. Have tested with wacom driver 6.3.40-2 and Photoshop v21.2.1.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

maybe you solved this, but i had the same problem and i put contrl+Alt+ Right mouse click on Pen setting for button 1 and works, but **you need to do the drag without press the tablet**. works with Alt+Right also with Control+Alt+Right but if you touch the screen then the default tool on this key (control+alt -duplicate or alt- picker) is activated.

So you just do the drag like a 2 milimietres from the screen and will work ;)